# Pass header parameters to dynamically invoked webservice

Tags: c#, web-services

I am trying to dynamically invoce a webservice which required header authentication
but I can't figure out how should I pass the required header credentials

My code:

```
public object[] GeneratewebserviceProxy(string WSDL)
{
        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(WSDL);
        System.IO.Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
        ServiceDescription description = ServiceDescription.Read(requestStream);
        string sdName = description.Services[0].Name;
        string Method_Name = description.Messages["LoginSoapIn"].Name.Replace("Request", "");
        Method_Name = Method_Name.Replace("SoapIn", "");
        ServiceDescriptionImporter importer = new ServiceDescriptionImporter();
        importer.ProtocolName = "Soap";
        importer.AddServiceDescription(description, null, null);
        CodeNamespace nmspace = new CodeNamespace();
        CodeCompileUnit unit1 = new CodeCompileUnit();
        unit1.Namespaces.Add(nmspace);
        ServiceDescriptionImportWarnings warning = importer.Import(nmspace, unit1);
        object[] objRet = null;
        if (warning == 0)
        {
            CodeDomProvider provider1 = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            string[] assemblyReferences = new string[3]{ "System.Web.Services.dll", "System.Xml.dll", "System.Data.dll" };
            CompilerParameters parms = new CompilerParameters(assemblyReferences);
            CompilerResults results = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp").CompileAssemblyFromDom(parms, unit1);
            object o = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(sdName);
            Type t = o.GetType();

            //PropertyInfo credentials = t.GetProperty("Credentials");
            //PropertyInfo credentials = t.GetProperty("Credentials");
           // credentials.SetValue(o, new NetworkCredential(username, passwd), null);

            MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod("Invoke", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);


            object[] webmethod_param = { "UserName", "Password" };
            object[] objParams = { Method_Name, webmethod_param };
            objRet = (object[])m.Invoke(o, objParams);
            if (objRet.Length > 0)
            {
                objRet = (object[])objRet[0];
            }
        }
        return objRet;
    }
```

The request should be as following:

```
  tem:AuthHeader>
     <tem:Username>UserName</tem:Username>
     <tem:Password>Password</tem:Password>
  </tem:AuthHeader
```

Ive tried both ways to pass the credentials (as you can se in the code)
 but nothing seems to work.

Comment: "nothing seems to work": does this mean you get an error (and if so, what error?), or those values are not retrievable from the header after the call, or...?

Comment: The Authentication doesn't work.
I'm not passing the credentials the right way

Answer (score 0):

You've to retrieve the ClientCredentials Property from ClientBase object. (the "o" in your code) and set Username and Password :

example :

```
ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
```

From MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms599072.aspx

*The ClientCredentials is accessed through the ClientCredentials property of the ClientBase class.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but isn't that what I've tried to achieve with the commented code?
From what I understand, client credentials and header credentials aren't the same thing.
What I did is:

Comment: PropertyInfo credentials = t.GetProperty("Credentials");
    PropertyInfo credentials = t.GetProperty("Credentials");
    credentials.SetValue(o, new NetworkCredential(username, passwd), null);

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't found an answer for this.
What I'm looking for is passing credentials in the header of the soap request.
And not in the way suggested above with client credentials

Comment: Passing Soap Header : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/whew6x7f(v=vs.80).aspx